# Modify JavaScript code to use on dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, iframe, redirect, joomla

Thanks for you replies. Sorry, if it doesn't make sense I will try again, I'm probably complicating things!

I have a frameset index.html, with top.php with is just the radio stream, under that is index.php which is the full joomla website with navigation and everything.

The problem is, if users find the website via a search engine. It will take take them to just the index.php and they won't get the frameset with the top.php. I was using this code in the top.php and index.php:

```
if(self.location==top.location)self.location="index.html";
```

which works great apart from it takes the user to index.php no matter what page they were looking for via a search engine.

So I found this article (look under 'A better way' section) which shows you how to code it so if the user's content is on about-us.html, it will take you to that page but still ensure it is in the frameset.
http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/frameredirect/frameredirect.html

I would like something like that but unfortunately with it being a Joomla website, I don't have page1.html, page2.html etc to be able to add the code and change it accordingly as per their instructions. I only have one page index.php which generates the pages dynamically 'on the fly'

So does anyone know a way I can do what I am wanting...
The frame set is at http://www.housocial.com/new/index.html

Just the joomla part http://www.housocial.com/new/index.php

Thanks again

Comment: I've read it three times and I'm not sure what you want ...

Comment: I'm not sure why this code you found is hard-coded to page1.html....  why can't you just make your own frameset?

Comment: update window.location('someurl'). I am not able to understand exactly waht you are asking. This is what I understood. you want to dynamically change your url, then use that logic.

Answer (score 0):

You may extract the filename via RegExp(I'm not sure if this is what you're asking for)

```
if(self==top)
{
 self.location="index.html?"+encodeURIComponent(location.href.match(/\w+\.html$/));
}
```

A more flexible solution that takes care of GET-parameters and anchors:

```
(
  function(url,pattern,query,hash)
  {
    var filename=location.pathname.match(pattern);
    if(filename)
    {
      url+=filename;
      if(query && location.search)
      {
        url+=location.search;
      }
      if(hash)
      {
        url+=location.hash
      }
    location.href=url;
    }
  }
)('http://www.housocial.com/new/index.php/', //target-URL
  /\w+\.html$/,       //pattern to search for
  1,                  //include QUERY_STRING
  1                   //include hash
  )
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I rewrote it hopefully with a better explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle I tried that but was getting 
http://www.housocial.com/new/index.php/index.html?null
when it should be something like
http://www.housocial.com/new/index.php/djs.html

Comment: My solution was looking for a filename at the end of the URL. I guess the URL also contains some GET-parameters, so the RegExp didn't match the href. You'll need to compare it against location.pathname instead. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle
My Javascript knowledge is very, very limited. So if I put the code in my frameset index.html as they say:

And your last code in my joomla index.php file, this should do what 
I want it to do?
I notice that your code is a function, do I need to call that function somewhere?
Thanks